# Variable column letter in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I want to make a relative conditional formatting macro that changes the column letter depending on which column I play the macro in. Can I do that?

```
=IF( OR($B6="WEEKEND", $B6="NYTÅR", $B6="JULEFERIE", $B6="PINSEFERIE", $B6="KR. HIMMEL", $B6="ST. BEDEDAG", $B6="PÅSKEFERIE", $B6="NYTÅR"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

So it should not say `$B6`, but `$(column letter)6`.
My macro looks like this (sorry for the Danish)

```
Sub LØ_SØ_HELLIGDAGS_FORMATERING()
'
' LØ_SØ_HELLIGDAGS_FORMATERING Makro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A420").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=HVIS( ELLER($B6=""WEEKEND""; $B6=""NYTÅR""; $B6=""JULEFERIE""; $B6=""PINSEFERIE""; $B6=""KR. HIMMEL""; $B6=""ST. BEDEDAG""; $B6=""PÅSKEFERIE""; $B6=""NYTÅR"");SAND;FALSK)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say _...depending on which column I play the macro in_, do you mean depending on which column is selected/active when the macro is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may do what you intend:

```
Sub LØ_SØ_HELLIGDAGS_FORMATERING()
'
' LØ_SØ_HELLIGDAGS_FORMATERING Makro
'

'
Dim myFormula As String
Dim cellAddress As String
    
    cellAddress = [SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),3),"1","")] & 6
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A420").Select
    myFormula = "=HVIS( ELLER($B6=""WEEKEND""; $B6=""NYTÅR""; $B6=""JULEFERIE""; $B6=""PINSEFERIE""; $B6=""KR. HIMMEL""; $B6=""ST. BEDEDAG""; $B6=""PÅSKEFERIE""; $B6=""NYTÅR"");SAND;FALSK)"
    myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "$B6", cellAddress)
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= myFormula
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

1. `[SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),3),"1","")]` captures the column of the active cell, `& 6` appends 6 and the result (in the format that you want: `$(column letter)6`) is written to `cellAddress`.
2. After that I left the original part of your code where you change the selection.
3. I moved your original formula to the variable `myFormula`.
4. Then I simply replaced `$B6` with whatever value was written into `cellAddress` in step 1.